# Does garbage collection change the object addresses in Java?

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm

I read that garbage collection can lead to memory fragmentation problem at run-time. To solve this problem, compacting is done by the JVM where it takes all the active objects and assigns them contiguous memory. 
This means that the object addresses must change from time to time? Also, if this happens,

1. Are the references to these objects also re-assigned?
2. Won't this cause significant performance issues? How does Java cope with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that garbage collection can lead to memory fragmentation problem at run-time.

This is not an exclusive problem of garbage collected heaps. When you have a manually managed heap and free memory in a different order than the preceding allocations, you may get a fragmented heap as well. And being able to have different lifetimes than the last-in-first-out order of automatic storage aka stack memory, is one of the main motivations to use the heap memory.

> To solve this problem, compacting is done by the JVM where it takes all the active objects and assigns them contiguous memory.

Not necessarily all objects. Typical implementation strategies will divide the memory into logical regions and only move objects from a specific region to another, but not all existing objects at a time. These strategies may incorporate the age of the objects, like generational collectors moving objects of the young generation from the Eden space to a Survivor space, or the distribution of the remaining objects, like the “Garbage First” collector which will, like the name suggests, evacuate the fragment with the highest garbage ratio first, which implies the smallest work to get a free contiguous memory block.

> This means that the object addresses must change from time to time?

Of course, yes.

> Also, if this happens,
>
> 1. Are the references to these objects also re-assigned?

The specification does not mandate how object references are implemented. An indirect pointer may eliminate the need to adapt all references, see also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57725764/2711488). However, for JVMs using direct pointers, this does indeed imply that these pointers need to get adapted.

> 2. Won't this cause significant performance issues? How does Java cope with it?

First, we have to consider what we gain from that. To “eliminate fragmentation” is not an end in itself. If we don’t do it, we have to scan the reachable objects for gaps between them and create a data structure maintaining this information, which we would call “free memory” then. We also needed to implement memory allocations as a search for matching chunks in this data structure or to split chunks if no exact match has been found. This is a rather expensive operation compared to an allocation from a contiguous free memory block, where we only have to bump the pointer to the next free byte by the required size.

Given that allocations happen much more often than garbage collection, which only runs when the memory is full (or a threshold has been crossed), this does already justify more expensive copy operations. It also implies that just using a larger heap can solve performance issues, as it reduces the number of required garbage collector runs, whereas the number of survivor objects will not scale with the memory (unreachable objects stay unreachable, regardless of how long you defer the collection). In fact, deferring the collection raises the chances that more objects became unreachable in the meanwhile. Compare also with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54619104/2711488).

The costs of adapting references are not much higher than the costs of traversing references in the marking phase. In fact, non-concurrent collectors could even combine these two steps, transferring an object on first encounter and adapting subsequently encountered references, instead of marking the object. The actual copying is the more expensive aspect, but as explained above, it is reduced by not copying all objects but using certain strategies based on typical application behavior, like generational approaches or the “garbage first” strategy, to minimize the required work.

Answer (score 0):

If you move an object around the memory, its address will change. Therefore, references pointing to it will need to be updated. Memory fragmentation occurs when an object in a contigous (in memory) sequence of objects gets deleted. This creates a *hole* in the memory space, which is generally bad because contigous chunks of memory have faster access times and a higher probability of fitting in chache lines, among other things. It should be noted that the use of indirection tables can prevent reference updates up to the maximum level of indirection used.

Garbage collection has a moderate performance overhead, not just in Java but in other languages as well, such as C# for example. As how Java copes with this, the strategies for performing garbage collection and how to minimize its impact on performance depends on the particular JVM being used, since each JVM can implement garbage collection however it pleases; the only requirement is that it meets the JVM specification.

However, as a programmer, there are some best practices you should follow to make the best out of garbage collection and to minimze its performance hit on your application. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14403774/12188799), [also this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2484079/12188799), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56373929/12188799), [this blog post](https://blog.overops.com/5-tips-for-reducing-your-java-garbage-collection-overhead/), and [this other blog post](https://blog.overops.com/improve-your-application-performance-with-garbage-collection-optimization/). You might want to check the [JVM specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/) but it's a bit dense.

Comment: References don't necessarily have to be updated. There can be an indirection table.

Comment: @user207421 yes, added it for completeness sake.